# running autoit/autohotkey scripts from server? or other automation alternatives?

Tags: automation, autoit

I have some scripts (AutoIt) browsing YouTube for list of trending videos etc. It involves no mouse clicks (just keystrokes). The script takes a long time to finish and I can't use my PC during this time (it needs the window activated to work on it).

Is there anything I can do about this? Can these scripts run from a server or some stuff like that?

Comment: If your server has a Desktop which can be blocked during the program run, why not? But if you want to manage everything automatically without using a graphical frontend (and sending AutoIt keystrokes is using such) you would go better with another language, because AutoIt is especially designed for GUI Interaction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Johannes said, AutoIt probably wouldn't be suitable (and likewise AutoHotkey), but you could check out the many GUI and web testing frameworks that exist for other languages. With some of those, you can run a "headless" browser (a program that navigates the web just like a browser, but has no visible window); or you can run a standard browser on a virtual display like a Xvfb X11 server. This would be easiest if the server (or wherever it's going to run) is running a Unix-like OS, but it may be possible with Windows too.

Selenium Webdriver seems to be a very popular choice for scripting and testing actual browsers. It's natively Java but has bindings for languages like Ruby. It can also hook into something called HtmlUnit, which is also Java; that's one of the more popular headless browsers. Another (a relative newcomer) is phantom.js, which is in Javascript but (again) has bindings for other languages.

Answer (score 2):

I've run into a similar problem: got to run automation with AutoIt on a Windows Server and the whole thing had got to be headless. Using Remote Desktop simply didin't work because then I'd had to keep a client opened and maximized all the time.

Short solution: install a VNC server in the Windows Server, open a client from another computer, log in and close the client. As the AutoIt script was being started by a Jenkins job, before closing the client the Jenkins applet had to be started via web interface.

By the way, I've had this idea from this post: [How to run remote headless GUI automation](http://autumnator.wordpress.com/2011/11/18/how-to-run-remote-headless-gui-automation/).

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know this will not work unless the user account is logged on. You could try to see if you could convert it to an exe and run this as a service, but even then I don't think this will work. Let me know if you found out!

Answer (score 0):

You can either:

Hide your window (SetWindowState @SW_HIDE) or something like that...
and use ControlClicks (if the they are original controls!)

or

Hide your window and use SendControl

or

use SendKeepActive

or

use OLEObjects like ie.au3 for automation.

Good Luck